# redirect folder subdomain to subdomain.domain.com in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a domain name `domain.com` and some folders inside it. When i am accessing the folders inside this domain i can access the folder like this.

```
http://www.domain.com/folder
```

I want to convert this url with htaccess to

```
http://www.folder.domain.com
```

I would like to have similar urls for all folders so its a wildcard entry.
Please tell me how can it be done with htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomains.domain.com/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @progsource- i added the snippet.

Comment: Did you setup the wildcard serveralias in the apache config?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/.*)?$ http://www.$1.domain.com$2 [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: didnt work again.am just putting this in root path htaccess file and restart the apache.is any thing i m missing in this

Comment: I add the part for the subdomain to folder redirect

Comment: Without htaccess, when you try with `http://www.folder.domain.com` that show the same page as with `http://www.domain.com` ?

Comment: No when i m using your solution,Its getting redirected to url i want but there its showing webpage not avaialble.when i m trying http://www.domain.com/folder,its redirected to http://www.folder.domain.com,but its showing webpage not available

Answer (score 0):

To redirect requests to www.example.com/blog to blog.example.com, try this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://blog.example.com/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^blog/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L,QSA]
```

For other you have to set dynamic name and pass as parameter, for simple blog you can take help of this question.

Comment: if we want to set for all folders rather than doing only for one as u have done for blog folder.hw can we do for al?